# How to navigate to a new page using Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

On following the normal routing procedure, by making different components, after clicking the Submit button, the content of the next component appears bellow the button itself (as  is below the submit button)

[image]

But I want to go to a different page altogether after clicking the Submit button, like the following image.

[image]

On clicking the Submit button on the left page, I want to go to a new page which will show Hello Member

The following is what I am doing, and as a result the content of the child component (i.e, Hello Member) is getting appended below.

`<button mat-raised-button color="primary" id="button" type="submit" routerLink="/page2" routerLinkActive="active">Submit</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

But that is not what I want.

On clicking the Submit button I want to be directed to a completely new page where Hello Member should appear, as I have showed in the second image.

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Why not using router?

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/router and/or run through https://angular.io/tutorial. If you're still in the sketching stage, you're not ready for a question on SO; try implementing something.

Comment: Nice handwriting

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have read that article. My point is the content of the new component gets appended below the root component. Is there any way that I can navigate to a different page altogether with different content?

Comment: *Is* that your point? Because if so, why do you not say it **in your question?** If you've read it, what have you *done* with it? Give a [mcve]; we can't tell you why your code is wrong if you don't actually provide it. Do you have the router outlet *alongside* the root component? If so, probably that's the problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the question now.

Comment: Then what exactly is unexpected? The router loads the component into the outlet. You're getting exactly the behaviour you asked for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The second image that I showed, that is what I want. Not the one where Hello Member appears below the Submit button.

Comment: I think Steve posted a good question and the doc doesn't provide a good example showing the solution. Though one can figure it out by playing around different positions of router-outlet, it's still good to post a question here in case there are simpler alternative solutions. @jonrsharp instead of questioning the author, it'd be more helpful if you could give the solution directly like what DeborahK did.

Comment: @eaglesky the OP posted photographs of sketches and no [mre], the first revision didn't even include the tiny bit of code they've added since; it's most certainly *not* a good question by the standards in [ask]. Deborah's willingness to enable it doesn't make this acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate your components differently.

The `<router-outlet>` defines *where* the routed component appears. So your code (as written) is routing to exactly where you are telling it to.

You need to instead add the `<router-outlet>` to a higher level component. Then initially route your first component to that router outlet. And when the user clicks submit, route your new component to that router outlet.

For example:

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**page1.component.html**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
        id="button" type="submit" 
        routerLink="/page2" routerLinkActive="active">
   Submit
</button>
```

**page2.component.html**

```
<h2>Hello Member</h2>
```

I have a complete routing example here:

https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Answer (score -1):

in angular, you can use something called Route.

The easiest way to start with is the tour of heroes 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-example

Check out at this files : app-routing-module, app-module and at the html (app for router-outlet) and hero detail for params usages.

In your case you can use a router-outlet, have a button with a (click) event and redirect your user using something like `<a *ngIf="formOk" [routerLink]="/link">Link text</a>`